# Como faço para retorna no json a foreign key no Spring Boot?

Tags: jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

Como vocês podem ver ele está retornando as cidades sem nenhum problemas na seguinte URL: `http://localhost:8080/cidades`, observem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é um retorno vindo direto do banco de dados com um `select * from cidade`, você conseguem ver alguma diferença?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebem que no atributo **codigo_estado** aparece no SQL realizado no banco de dados, porém esse mesmo atributo não aparece na lista feita pela API Java do Spring Boot, pois gostaria também que o atributo **codigo_estado** também fosse retornado no Json da API Java.

**Como é que eu faço para a API conseguir retorna esse atributo?**

Aqui logo abaixo está os códigos respondente a lista retornada pela URL: `http://localhost:8080/cidades`

**O controller:**

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.resource;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Cidade;
import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Estado;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.CidadeRepository;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.EstadoRepository;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.filter.CidadeFilter;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cidades")
public class CidadeResource {


    @Autowired
    private  CidadeRepository cidadeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private  EstadoRepository estadoRepository;


    @GetMapping
    public List<Cidade> pesquisarPorCidade(CidadeFilter cidadeFilter){
        return cidadeRepository.filtrar(cidadeFilter);
    }

    @GetMapping("/estados")
    public List<Estado> pesquisarPorEstado(){
        return estadoRepository.findAll();
    }


}
```

**O repositório**:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Cidade;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.cidade.CidadeRepositoryQuery;

public interface CidadeRepository extends JpaRepository<Cidade, Long> , CidadeRepositoryQuery {


}
```

**A interface da implementação do filtro:**

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.repository.cidade;

import java.util.List;

import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Cidade;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.filter.CidadeFilter;

public interface CidadeRepositoryQuery {

        public List<Cidade> filtrar(CidadeFilter cidadeFilter);
}
```

**A própria implementação:**

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.repository.cidade;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Cidade;
import com.algaworks.brewer.model.Cidade_;
import com.algaworks.brewer.repository.filter.CidadeFilter;

public class CidadeRepositoryImpl implements CidadeRepositoryQuery {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Override
    public List<Cidade> filtrar(CidadeFilter cidadeFilter) {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Cidade> criteria = builder.createQuery(Cidade.class);
        Root<Cidade> root = criteria.from(Cidade.class);

        Predicate[] predicates = criarRestricoes(cidadeFilter, builder, root);
        criteria.where(predicates);

        TypedQuery<Cidade> query = manager.createQuery(criteria);
        return query.getResultList();
    }


    private Predicate[] criarRestricoes(CidadeFilter cidadeFilter, CriteriaBuilder builder,
            Root<Cidade> root) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(cidadeFilter.getNome())) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(
                    builder.lower(root.get(Cidade_.nome)), "%" + cidadeFilter.getNome().toLowerCase() + "%"));
        }





        return predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]);
    }


}





//if (cidadeFilter.getEstado() != null) {
//  predicates.add(
//          builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Cidade_.estado.getName()), cidadeFilter.getEstado().getNome()));
//}
```

Estou ansioso pelo retorno!

Esse é o código da cidade:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cidade")
public class Cidade implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @NotBlank(message = "Nome é obrigatório")
    private String nome;

    @NotNull(message = "Estado é obrigatório")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_estado")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Estado estado;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public boolean temEstado() {
        return estado != null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cidade other = (Cidade) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
}
}
```

E da entidade Estado:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "estado")
public class Estado implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String sigla;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getSigla() {
        return sigla;
    }

    public void setSigla(String sigla) {
        this.sigla = sigla;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Estado other = (Estado) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Vocês podem perceber que existe um `@JsonIgnore` no `private Estado estado` é como estivesse sendo ignorado, eu peguei esse código de outro lugar é por isso que ele se encontra ai, eu preciso fazer um tempo de alteração de tal forma que o `LAZY` ainda funcione.

veja o trecho:

```
@NotNull(message = "Estado é obrigatório")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_estado")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Estado estado;
```

Comment: Pode postar o código da sua entidade `Cidade`? Eu acho que você deve estar mapeando `Estado` em um relacionamento `@ManyToOne` (o que é correto em JPA). Para fazer o que você quer provavelmente terá que criar um novo *field* `codigoEstado` com a anotação `@Column(name="codigo_estado", updatable=false, insertable=false)` mas essa não é a melhor das idéias (na prática o modelo relacional está "vazando" para camadas superiores da aplicação)

Comment: @wladyband Post para nós suas entidades. Seria de grande valia para avaliarmos como estão os relacionamentos e mapeamentos.

Comment: @YoungerAuad , acabei de atualizar a postagem colocando o código das duas entidades, poderia dá uma olhada para mim por favor?

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly dá uma olhada por favor?  eu atualizei a postagem

Comment: @wladyband, tente minha sugestão do comentário acima: `@Column(name="codigo_estado", updatable=false, insertable=false) private Long codigoEstado;` na prática porém talvez seja melhor criar um objeto diferente para o serviço e copiar os valores necessários de Cidade e Estado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@wladyband,

Se entendi bem seu problema, você gostaria de exibir o código do estado junto aos dados da cidade. Além disso, você deseja também manter o `@JsonIgnore` no relacionamento `@ManyToOne` com a classe Estado, pois, parece não querer impedir que todo o objeto estado seja convertido e que todos os dados do estado estejam junto a cidade, mas somente o seu código.

---

**OBS**: A título de curiosidade, desde a versão 2.6 do [Jackson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackson_(API)) (biblioteca para processamento de Json, que é default no Spring MVC), nós temos uma anotação mais intuitiva que o `@JsonIgnore`, que é `@JsonProperty` e que você poderá controlar o acesso de forma mais detalhada:

```
@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String myField;

@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String myField2;

@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_WRITE)
private String myField3;
```

Dê uma olha melhor na [documentação](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.Access.html) dessa anotação.

---

Dentro de tudo isso que percebi que deseja fazer, só vai lhe restar a opção de criar um novo atributo dentro da classe cidade para conter apenas o código do Estado, sem realizar relacionamento `@ManyToOne`, e não utilizar nenhuma anotation de ignorar para que seja serializado. Nesse campo faremos tratamento para que ele não seja usado nem para ser inserido no banco nem para atualizar nada relacionado no banco, ou seja, será um campo  *transient* ou apenas para leitura. Segue abaixo como seria:

```
package com.algaworks.brewer.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cidade")
public class Cidade implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;

    @NotBlank(message = "Nome é obrigatório")
    private String nome;

    @NotNull(message = "Estado é obrigatório")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_estado")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Estado estado;

    @Column(name="codigo_estado", updatable=false, insertable=false) 
    private Long codigoEstado;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Estado getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public boolean temEstado() {
        return estado != null;
    }

    public Long getCodigoEstado() {
        return codigoEstado;
    }

    public void setCodigoEstado(Long codigoEstado) {
        this.codigoEstado = codigoEstado;
    }

    //........
}
```

Qualquer coisa, por favor, informe para que possa tentar melhorar a explicação. Não sei se capturei toda a sua necessidade e restrição.

Comment: ficou certinho, do jeito que eu queria, muito obrigado!    :)